# Get Separate Objects from String Object

Tags: java

Geeks,

I have a String in java having the following value

{"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Uaq","organizationCode":"S05","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":1} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, HiQ Shj EMR","organizationCode":"S18","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":2} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Dxb","organizationCode":"S16","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":3} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Dib","organizationCode":"S17","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":4} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Central Parts Depot","organizationCode":"S01","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":5} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Awr","organizationCode":"S02","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":6} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Shj","organizationCode":"S03","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":7} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Ajm","organizationCode":"S04","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":8} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Rak","organizationCode":"S06","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":9} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Kal","organizationCode":"S07","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":10} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Fuj","organizationCode":"S08","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":11} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Kho","organizationCode":"S09","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":12} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Dhd","organizationCode":"S10","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":13} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Sat","organizationCode":"S11","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":14} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Gus","organizationCode":"S12","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":15} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, Szr","organizationCode":"S13","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":16} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Showroom Sales, HiQ MSF","organizationCode":"S19","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":17} {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Accessories, PDI","organizationCode":"S21","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":18}

How do i get a string object for each representation like {"organizationName":"Spare Parts - Accessories, PDI","organizationCode":"S21","retailPrice":"32","onHandQuantity":"0","index":18}

So basically i would get 18 String objects from the above.

Thanks

Comment: Using split for example, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: I tried Split but not able to make a regex for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to extract value between curly braces and format it back to json

```
    String s1 = ""; //your string
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s1);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String.format("{%s}", matcher.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: thnks. It worked. Possible to explain me this Patter and Matcher

Comment: It`s better to refer to official documentation. [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)